# sql sum data from multiple tables with entries from both tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables tbl1 and tbl2 where both have the columns [PartID] and [Amount] and [Date].

I want a query to return something like this :

```
PartID | Date | SUM_tbl1 | SUM_tbl2
```

PartID 1 maybe in tbl1 but not in tbl2 and vice versa and each PART ID has multiple rows in both tables.

I want both SUM columns to show SUM of each Part IDs in that table. And I want to see SUM as of 6/30/2017.

Please help! and thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be explicit about which RDBMS you are using. Is it MySQL or MS Access (or perhaps MS Access with linked tables to MySQL?)

Comment: Hi Erik, It is MS Access and just running the query in SQL View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest?  First, use a UNION to assemble a single table with the raw rows you'd need:

```
select PartID, Date, Amt as Table1Entry, NULL as Table2Entry from tbl1
UNION ALL
select PartID, Date, NULL as Table1Entry, Amt as Table2Entry from tbl2
```

... next, now that you've got both tables's data together, just sum from that as a subquery:

```
select PartID, Date, Sum(Table1Entry) as SumTable1, Sum(Table2Entry) as SumTable2
from
(
    select PartID, Date, Amt as Table1Entry, NULL as Table2Entry from tbl1
    UNION ALL
    select PartID, Date, NULL as Table1Entry, Amt as Table2Entry from tbl2
) mySubquery
GROUP BY PartID, Date
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can someone tell me how I can insert a WHERE clause there to look up Amount totals for tbl1 and tbl2 columns - say before 8/31/2017. Or even better if I can have a line inserted in the query output that gives me the aggregate SUM at the end of each month!

Comment: To be honest, you can do a WHERE clause in either part.  Think of it this way, that "subquery"?  It's acting like a table that the main query is going against.  So you could put a WHERE clause in the main query, which would filter down entries that *are* in the subquery, or put it in the subquery itself.  Don't worry about the efficiency either way - the SQL engine's good at optimizing (it's not like it's creating an actual table with all the records from the subquery.)

Comment: I have another question: 
tbl_1 has PartID, Part Type, Year Begin, Year End, CompID, Service Date, Effective Date, Description, Type, Ref#, Date Cleared. tbl_2 has PartID, Part Type, CompID, Trasanction Date, Amount, Description, Invoice#. I want to combine these two tables. Transaction Date from tbl_2 can be renamed as Service Date. Type from tbl_2 can be renamed as Description, Invoice# from tbl_2 can be renamed as Ref#. PartID, Part Type and CompID have the same field names.

Comment: Take a look at the first snippet in my answer - and pay attention to the places where it uses a column name, and the places where it uses a NULL.  When it's grabbing from tbl1, notice how it's creating a 'Table2Entry' that's just NULL?  That's because it's creating a column (with no data) that lines up with the entry in tbl2.  If it helps, try running both of those SELECT queries by themselves, and see how it creates two results that have the exact same columns.  That's what you need to do with your tables - create two SELECTS that have the same columns (and then you can UNION ALL them.)

Comment: Or put another way: if you had a table with columns ID, Alpha, Bravo, Charlie and another table with columns ID, Alpha, and Zulu, your select statements would be: "Select ID, Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, NULL as Zulu" and "Select ID, Alpha, NULL as Bravo, NULL as Charlie, Zulu"

Comment: Thank you Kevin. It is displaying the output. However the output is not displaying the exact same rows from the source files when I also want it to show the duplicate rows as well. Any solution to this? For ex. if row 1 and row2 both have ABC in columns XYZ in tbl_1, the output is displaying only row 1 and not row2. Help please?

Comment: Got it. Just added UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: Hi! So there are 5million+ rows in this output. Can you tell me how to add a column in the output with sequential numbers from 1 through 5,000,000 please?

My query right now is SELECT..FROM..UNION ALL
SELECT..FROM..;
How can I incorporate something in the query now to show another column that uniquely identifies each row (to help differentiate two exact same rows) Thanks!

Comment: The idea behind the site isn't "solve a development chain", but to have specific answers for specific issues.  That way, if someone else has the same issue, they can find a solution by searching for it.  *Don't* ask that particular question, though - I'd be *very* surprised if there isn't an answer to it already on the site.  Search for it instead.